# Generics vs. JavaFX

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I fail to understand why there are certain ways my code doesn't work properly. This is the short but very dirty (who'd put a `Stage` into a `TableView`?) small sample code:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class JavaFxCellFactory extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(JavaFxCellFactory.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    TableView<Stage> tableView = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<Stage, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("Col-Title");
    tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Stage, String>("title"));

    // --- start of options:
    // option 1:
    Callback<TableColumn<Stage, String>, TableCell<Stage, String>> cellFactory = createTextCellFactory();

    // option 2:
//    Callback<TableColumn<Stage, String>, TableCell<Stage, String>> cellFactory = column -> createTextCell();

    // option 3:
//    TextFieldTableCell<Stage, String> cell = createTextCell();
//    Callback<TableColumn<Stage, String>, TableCell<Stage, String>> cellFactory = column -> cell;
    // --- end of options

    tableColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    tableView.getColumns().setAll(tableColumn);
    tableView.getItems().setAll(stage);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
    stage.setTitle("my title");
    stage.show();
  }

  private <M> Callback<TableColumn<M, String>, TableCell<M, String>> createTextCellFactory() {
    return column -> createTextCell();
  }

  private <M> TextFieldTableCell<M, String> createTextCell() {
    return new TextFieldTableCell<>(new DefaultStringConverter());
  }

}
```

You can see the three options I put in there. Options 1 and 2 show "my title" as a value in the table, while option 3 does not. I know that during runtime generics are somewhat lost, but somehow they still exist and keep things typed. My guess is that something along the way causes the cell factory to think that the value is not a `String` or the general type of the model of the bean is not `Stage` any more.

I need `cell` as I want to do more stuff with it before I create the lambda for the factory, which is why I need to make option 3 work.

Who wants to help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are re-using the same cell. The other two options actually create a new instance for every call, which is how the factory should function.

Comment: @sillyfly Ah, I see, thanks. Well, after understanding that I had to rewrite my code slightly and I'm now able to go along with option 2 where the right side of that lambda now calls another method prior to returning the text field.